# How can I see a list of my Custom Post Types of the last term I was in?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters

Sorry about the title I do not know how to put the question in the form of a title very well but my question if very descriptive.

Iv been meaning to asking this question for a while now and would really! like to know so im going to be as descriptive and detailed as I possibly can. Let me start of by letting you know what the situation is and how things are working.

I have one `Custom Post Type of "Products"` created by the Custom Post Type UI Plugin

Along with `two custom Taxonomies of "Types" and "Countries"` used as filters for my products in my Taxonomy.php

Ok so now that you understand the set up this is what im doing, lets say I have a shirt store and I am filtering through my products based on "Countries" and "Types"

> Countries:
>
> - USA
> - China
> - France
>
> Types:
>
> - Cotton
> - Silk
> - Polyester

Now on my taxonomy.php where I list all custom post types of products on the left I have a list of all of my `Countries` and `Types` so people can filter through them and see the appropriate products.

**The problem:**

> When I go into my shirts page where I see ALL of my shirts I can see
>   on the left side the "Types" so lets say I then click on the type of
>   `cotton` now I can see all of my custom post types of products that
>   are `cotton` which is great but now this is the problem. When im on
>   the `cotton` term of the taxonomy `Types` I can see my countries
>   terms on the left and when I click on lets say `USA` I see ALL of the
>   `Products` listed under the term of USA But thats **NOT** what I want.
>   I wanted it so that when im on cotton and then click on the `Country
>   Term of USA` I will only see products of `cotton` with the the Country
>   Term of USA **NOT** all of the products under the term of USA.

My code in functions.php for my products in my taxonomy page to display properly with paginations:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'name' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
});
```

Then in my taxonomy.php I have my products and my custom taxonomy filters on the left set up like so:

```
// listing all of my Types Terms of the current term on the left using it as filters for my shirts.
<div class="categories types">
<p>Types</p>
<ul>
<?php

//get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_list_categories
 $args = array(
  'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
  'taxonomy' => 'types',
  'hide_empty' => 1,
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'show_count'     => 1,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'depth'  => 1,
  'title_li' => ''
    );
 wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
</ul>

</div><!--categories end-->



// listing all of my Types Terms of the current term on the left using it as filters for my shirts.
<div class="categories countries">
<p>Types</p>
<ul>
<?php

//get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_list_categories
 $args = array(
  'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
  'taxonomy' => 'countries',
  'hide_empty' => 1,
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'show_count'     => 1,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'depth'  => 1,
  'title_li' => ''
    );
 wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
</ul>

</div><!--categories end-->



//listing my products custom post types
<div class="products">

<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

//the loop
<?php the_field('title'); ?>
<?php the_field('image'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

//pagination
<?php 
global $wp_query;

$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

  echo paginate_links(array(
      'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
      'format' => '/page/%#%',
      'current' => $current_page,
      'total' => $total_pages,
      'before_page_number' => '<div class="pagination-navigation">',
      'after_page_number' => '</div>'

    ));
}
?>

</div><!--products end-->
```

So as you can see above that is my functions.php and my taxonomy.php.

So I have been thinking a lot about this and what logic I can use and iv only come up with maybe one way this is possible. So my taxonomy of Countries is the problem because when I click on a country like `USA` I want to see the countries of the previous term I was on which was `cotton` and **NOT** all of the countries under `USA`.

Sorry for the long explanation but [CLICK HERE](http://essemail.com/question.jpg) to visually see what I want to achieve and you will fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `wp_list_categories()` you get a list of terms, each one linked to its archive page. I think what you need is a form to filter the products, not a list of archive term links, so you can keep the selected filters between requests, for example, using `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIES`.

Example using `$_POST`:

```
<?php
//taxonomies you want to filter
$taxonomies = array( "countries", "types" );
function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomy, $args){
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
    $output = '<select id="'.$taxonomy.'" name="'.$args['name'].'" multiple>';
    foreach($terms as $term){
        in_array($term->term_id, $args['selected']) ? $sel = ' selected' : $sel = '';
        $output .='<option value="'.$term->term_id.'"'.$sel.'>'.$term->name.'</option>';
    }
    $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
}
?>
<?php
//Set the action of the from to custom post type archive
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('products');?>" id="products-filter-form">
<?php
foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    //check if there is a previously selected terms
    $selected = (!empty($_POST['tax_input'][$taxonomy])) ? ($_POST['tax_input'][$taxonomy]) : array();
    $selected = array_map('intval', $selected);

    $args = array(
         'hide_empty' => false,
         'selected'   => $selected,
         'name'       => 'tax_input['.$taxonomy.'][]',
    );
    echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomy,$args);
}
?>
<button type="submit">Filter</button>
<button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

And now the in the preg_get_posts action you add the selected taxonomy terms to the query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_pre_get_post' );
function cyb_pre_get_post($query){

    if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'products' ) ) {
        //taxonomies you want to filter
        $taxonomies = array( "countries", "types" );
        $tax_input = isset($_POST['tax_input']) ? $_POST['tax_input'] : '';
        if(!empty($tax_input)){
            //Ready to construct the tax_query
            foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
                if(isset($tax_input[$taxonomy])) {
                    $value = array_map('intval', $tax_input[$taxonomy]);
                    if(!empty($value) && $value[0] != "0"){
                        $tax_query[] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $value
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            $query->set('tax_query',$tax_query);
            //The tax_query has been set
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: code tested with `category` and `post_tag` taxonomies and it is working. It may need some modifications to fully fit your needs.

Comment: hmm ok so iv read your code over and over again and tried out some tests and I see where your going with this but I see a lot of problem. One is that the parameters that I have `wp_list_categories` are no longer working. How would I be able to give that parameters? for instance I want the quantity of posts of that certain category to display to the right of the term. Thats just one parameter that I had but I would need about 4 more parameters meaning it would need to be customizable some how. And on top of that the filters do not work, it stays on the same items.

Comment: I dont mean to sounds like im criticizing or anything your code is actually amazing but it changes a lot about how I have everything already set up.

Comment: oh and by the way yes the taxonomy is hierarchical

Comment: As I said, the code may needs modifications to fully fit your needs. I've tested it with category and post_tag taxonomies and it is working filtering the posts within the selected categories and tags (I posted the code with category and post_tag mixed with your custom taonomies countries and types, I've edited the answer and fixed that typo). Note that in your code you was using `get_query_var( 'term' )` and `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )` and in my code the tax query is being modified with the selected terms.

Comment: ok well I can seen a list of all of my countries and types but when I try and filter them nothing happens. it just reloads the page and the items stay the same.

Comment: Yeah, I introduced a bug again, sorry. In my tests I was using the blog home page and I was cheking `is_home()`. In the answer the form is sent to "products" archive page not to home page, so `is_home()` should be replaced with `is_post_type_archive( 'products' )`. Answer edited. Sorry again.

Comment: It's ok no worries I really appreciate the help. But it's still the same thing, the page reloads but the products stay the same no matter what filter.

Comment: At this point is very difficult to say why it is not working for you. Can you try to debug the `$_POST` variable recieved in the `pre_get_posts` action hook? Can you verify that "products", "countries" and "types" are the correct slugs for the custom post type and taxonomies?.

Comment: Well heres the information on my custom taxonomies and post type. [click here](http://www.essemail.com/taxonomy.png).. and as far as the pre_get_posts go I just copied and pasted your code in my functions.php

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help further if you don't provide the debug information.

Comment: how can I provide the debug information?